# Is it possible to get Adderall or Ritalin in China?

Tags: china, medical

I have ADHD and going to move to China. Is it possible to get Adderall, Ritalin or equivalent ADHD drugs in China?

Answer (score 1):

Yes both are available in China, you may have to go to a foreign manager hospital but they are plenty specially in the bigger cities, if you are out in the rural areas you might have challenges though